# What's elasticsearch and is it safe to delete logstash?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch

I have an internal Apache server for testing purpose, not client facing.

I wanted to upgrade the server to apache 2.4, but there is no space left, so I was trying to delete some files on the server.

After checking file size, I found a folder /var/lib/elasticsearch takes 80g space. For example, /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.12.08 takes 60g already. I'm not sure what's elasticsearch. Is it safe if i delete this logstash? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) is a search engine, like a NoSql database, and it stores the data in indeces. What you are seeing is the data of one index.
Probobly someone was using the index aroung 2015 when the index was timestamped. 
I would just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that only you can answer that question.  One use for logstash+elastic search are to help make sense out of system logs.  That combination isn't normally setup by default, so I presume someone set it up at some time for some reason, and it has obviously done some logging.  Only you can know if it is still being used, or if it is safe to delete.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers pointed out Elastic search is a distributed search engine. And I believe an earlier user was pushing application or system logs using Logstash to this Elastic search instance. If you can find the source application, check if the log files are already there, if yes, then you can go ahead and delete your index. I highly doubt anyone still needs the logs back from 2015, but it is really your call to see what your application's archiving requirements are and then take necessary action.